# Rxjava tolist() not completing

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a problem with my RxJava callchain. The toList is not working properly. I would guess that it is that the toList() needs something to complete. That is why it is stuck. But i do not know how to solve this issue

**The code**

```
        mModel.getLocations()
            .flatMapIterable(new Function<List<Location>, List<Location>>(){
                @Override
                public List<Location> apply(final List<Location> locations) throws Exception {
                    return locations;
                }
            })
            .filter(new Predicate<Location>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(final Location location) throws Exception {
                    return location.searchExistInNameOrKeyWord(input);
                }
            })
            .toList()
            .map(new Function<List<Location>, List<Location>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Location> apply(List<Location> locations) throws Exception {                     
                    /** Doing some random work with the list and then returning */
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Location>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(final List<Location> locations) throws Exception {
                    mView.setAdapterItems(locations);
                }
            });
```

Maybe someone that is a lot better than me at RxJava could pinpoint what i am doing wrong.

**Update**

```
@Query("SELECT * from location")
Flowable<List<Location>> loadAllLocations();
```

The `mModel.getLocations()` just calls the loadAllLocations like above from the Room percistance storage

Comment: Well, is `mModel.getLocations()` actually completing?

Comment: added some more information  to the post. The only thing it does is to call the loadAllLocations from the storage

Answer (score 11):

I've never used Room before but according to this article: https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757

> Now, every time the user data is updated, our Flowable object will
>   emit automatically, allowing you to update the UI based on the latest
>   data. The Flowable will emit only when the query result contains at
>   least a row. When there is no data to match the query, the Flowable
>   will not emit, neither onNext nor onError.

So, `Flowable` reacts on every data change and that means `onComplete` would never be called. In that case you cannot use `toList()` operator because this stream will never complete.

Answer (score 0):

The Key Point for toList() operator is that It will wait for all the items to be emitted. Once its done mean onComplete() method must get called and there we will get our desirable result. If we are not using onComplete() or because of some reason onComplete() is not getting called then nothing will print.