# RxJava filter does not emit result to subscribe

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have RxJava filter to get POA's only that are not deleted(deactivated) and I am quite sure that I have one result, but I do not get any result in subscribe.

```
Disposable disposable = appDatabase.poaDao().getAllMine()
    .flatMap(poaDbs -> Flowable.fromIterable(poaDbs))
    .filter(poaDb -> !poaDb.isDeleted())
    .toList()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(poaDbs ->
                   view.onActivePoasIssuedByMe(poaDbs),
               throwable -> view.handleError(throwable));
```

What could be the reason? I have tried debugging but it never gets to sunbscribe().

Comment: is this related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139057/rxjava-tolist-not-completing ?

Comment: It could be since it returns all result after I remove toList, but I need to filter the data. Is there any other way to filter data in reactive way?

Comment: Define `getAllMine()` as `Single<List<POAwhatever>>` and you should get a single list of results to filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the Observable is not completing, so `.toList()` will never be executed.
You said you need to filter the list you are getting, but if that is the case, you have a different option.

Instead of doing this:

```
.flatMap(poaDbs -> Flowable.fromIterable(poaDbs))
    .filter(poaDb -> !poaDb.isDeleted())
    .toList()
```

You want to do:

```
.flatMapSingle(poaDbs -> Observable.fromIterable(poaDbs)
     .filter(poaDb -> !poaDb.isDeleted())
     .toList())
```

Note that the `.filter` and `.toList` operators are applied to the internal Observable.

Extra note: this is even easier when using Kotlin since it provides the `filter` operation on collections, and you don't have to rely on RxJava or Java8 streams